# How to stop mails to nobody? and is it a good idea?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

I noticed I ran out of space for the root partition on my server.  then after checking what's taking huge size. I found that /var/mail/nobody taking 1.4GB. how to stop postfix from using that much space for nobody or maybe preventing any mail from reaching nobody? and is that safe and good idea?

I also have virtualmin on the server if that's relevant.

Comment: don't post mails to nobody

Comment: First, you should _read_ the mail.

Comment: The `nobody` account is quite often the sender used in scripts and a large mailbox for nobody is frequently the result of a lot of bounce/error messages. Read the messages in the mailbox to determine if those are expected messages or indicative of abuse...

Comment: Do you need to receive/deliver mail on that system? You could disable local delivery + follow the others instructions.

Comment: You're right I should've read it first.  Turned out to be cron messages that showed snmp related messages. I thought I already uninstalled that, but turned out I installed it with php7. I uninstalled php7.0-snmp and I guess this should solve it. Thanks!